# Why are removed kernels still listed under dpkg?

Tags: kernel, cleanup

I removed several old kernels using `sudo apt-get purge`, but [they are still listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rUFD.png) when I run `dpkg --list 'linux-image-*'`. I can't figure out how to get rid of them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: They are listed because `dpkg -list` outputs the *package database*, which includes all known (to the system) packages, both installed and uninstalled, and the various status of each.

Comment: Study the first few lines of output from `$ dpkg --list | head -n 10`

Comment: @user535733 I didn't actually know that, but it makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg --list | grep linux-image | grep "^r"` will show kernels that have been removed. `dpkg --purge <package>` would remove it from the history as well -- but not really necessary.